# Koa-session getting reset after appending object to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa2, koa-session

I have a controller which looks up a character, and then does some stuff with it, the controller looks like:

```
router.post('/profile/characters', async ctx => {
    try {
        ctx.type = 'json';
        let req = ctx.request;
        if (!('charname' in req.body) || !('charserver' in req.body)) {
            return res.json({
                'success': false,
                error: 'You are missing either the character name, or server'
            });
        }

        let foundChar = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
            bnet.wow.character.aggregate({
                origin: 'us',
                realm: req.body.charserver,
                name: req.body.charname,
                fields: ['items', 'talents']
            }, (err, charData) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return rej(err);
                }
                return res(charData);
            });
        });


        if ('status' in foundChar) {
            if (foundChar.status === 'nok') {
                return ctx.body = {
                    'success': false,
                    error: 'There was an error looking up your character, please ensure its a US character, and has been logged into recently'
                };
            }
        }

        foundChar.items.level = foundChar.level;
        foundChar.items.class = foundChar.class;
        foundChar.items.thumbnail = foundChar.thumbnail;
        foundChar.items.name = foundChar.name;

        let {
            items, talents
        } = foundChar;

        let specF = talents.find(x => x.selected) || {};
        let charData = {
            items, specF
        };

        if ('legs' in items || 'hands' in items || 'shoulder' in items) {
            return ctx.body = {
                success: false,
                error: 'To verify it is your own character, please remove your (Shoulders, Hands, and Pants) from your character and try again.'
            };
        }

        ctx.session.foundChar = foundChar; // This line here
        console.log(ctx.session);
        ctx.body = {
            success: true,
            charData
        };

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        ctx.status = err.status || 500;
        ctx.body = {
            message: err.message
        };
    }
});
```

When it processes `ctx.session.foundChar = foundChar` it seems to reset my session for some reason, and logging the session shows `{}` instead of

```
{ 
   authenticated: true,
   userid: 1
   ...
}
```

But if I change `ctx.session.foundChar = "Hello";` < Works just fine.

I don't know if there is a data limit or something to the session or what as this wasn't an issue with `express-session` but I'm trying to convert it all over to Koa, anyways not sure why my session is getting reset.

Example of what `foundChar` looks like

```
{ userid: 1,
  username: 'Blah',
  authenticated: true,
  userLevel: 5,
  hasMainCharacter: true,
  foundChar:
   { lastModified: 1453702285000,
     name: 'Blah',
     realm: 'Mal\'Ganis',
     battlegroup: 'Vindication',
     class: 4,
     race: 5,
     gender: 0,
     level: 100,
     achievementPoints: 6335,
     thumbnail: 'internal-record-3684/9/119507209-avatar.jpg',
     calcClass: 'c',
     faction: 1,
     items:
      { averageItemLevel: 714,
        averageItemLevelEquipped: 573,
        head: [Object],
        neck: [Object],
        back: [Object],
        chest: [Object],
        wrist: [Object],
        waist: [Object],
        feet: [Object],
        finger1: [Object],
        finger2: [Object],
        trinket1: [Object],
        trinket2: [Object],
        mainHand: [Object],
        offHand: [Object],
        level: 100,
        class: 4,
        thumbnail: 'internal-record-3684/9/119507209-avatar.jpg',
        name: 'Blah' },
     talents: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     totalHonorableKills: 258 } }
```

So this logs properly, but then after refreshing the page im no longer authenticated and `ctx.session` is `{}`

Comment: Is the session stored in a cookie? You might be going over the maximum cookie length once your session is serialized to a string.

Comment: why are you saving an entire object into the session? the session should be as small as possible. just save the character ID, then grab the ID from the database on every request

Comment: @mikefrey you are correct, it is so, I answered question including that point.

Comment: @JonathanOng I agree, I provided option for it in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem

Your problem is, because of [koajs/session](https://github.com/koajs/session) usage which is

> Simple cookie-based session middleware for Koa.

Which means when `ctx.session` is being serialized into json and stored in cookie after each request and is being deserialized before each request.

Unfortunately cookie has limited size and when you try to store big object into it with `ctx.session.foundChar = foundChar` it exceeds maximum cookie size and results currupted session cookie.

For same reason `ctx.session.foundChar = "Hello"` works, because json size does not exceed max cookie size.

## Solution

Use db based storage for session, good choice for it could be [koa-session-storage](https://github.com/hiddentao/koa-session-store).

Look [session storage layer](https://github.com/hiddentao/koa-session-store#session-storage-layer) for configuration options

> The `store` configuration option specifies where the session data is
>   stored. If omitted or set to `"cookie"` then session data will be
>   stored in the cookie itself.
>
> If you wish to store session data elsewhere (e.g. in Mongo, Redis,
>   etc.) then you must set this to an object which exposes the following
>   API:
>
> - **load(sid)** - load session data for given session id    * `sid` -
>     *{String}* session identifier.    * returns a Promise, Thunk or generator which returns a JSON string of the session object data.
> - **save(sid, data)** - save session data for given session id    *
>     `sid` - *{String}* session identifier.    * `data` - _{String} session
>     data converted to JSON string.    * returns a Promise, Thunk or
>     generator which returns once data is saved.
> - **remove(sid)** - remove session data for given session id    *
>     `sid` - *{String}* session identifier.    * returns a Promise, Thunk
>     or generator which returns once removal is complete.
>
> The following storage layers are currently available:
>
> - MongoDB -
>     [koa-session-mongo](https://npmjs.org/package/koa-session-mongo)